Error al ejecutar un script de bash en bin
Cree un sript de bash en bin, el script se llama git.sh y se trata de un programa que automatiza los comandos de git, como git status, init, commit, etc. Yo lo cree en bin y modifique el archivo .bashrc poniendole esto al final: export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" , para que el script se pudiera ejeuctar en cualquier ruta y funciona porque tengo varios archivos .sh y se ejecutan bien, pero este script git.sh no lo hace.
Este es el resultado al intentar ejecutarlo:
-bash: ./git.sh: no se puede ejecutar: no se ha encontrado el fichero requerido

Y este el mi código:
#!/bin/bash
# Comandos de Git automatizados

# Clonar un repositorio

echo "Comandos de Git automatizados:"
read -p "¿Quieres clonar un repositorio? (s/n): " clonar

if [[ $clonar == "s" ]]; then
    read -p "¿Quieres cambiar de ruta para clonar el repo? (s/n): " respuesta

    if [[ $respuesta == "s" ]]; then
        read -p "Ingresa la nueva ruta: " nueva_ruta
        cd "$nueva_ruta" || { echo "No se pudo cambiar de carpeta"; exit 1; }
    fi

    read -p "Ingrese la URL: " url
    git clone "$url" || { echo "Error al clonar el repositorio"; exit 1; }
    exit 0
fi

read -p "Ingrese la ruta de la carpeta para aplicarle Git: " carpeta
cd "$carpeta" || { echo "No se pudo cambiar de carpeta"; exit 1; }

# Inicializar la carpeta o no

read -p "¿Su carpeta esta inicializada? (s/n): " estado_init

if [[ $estado_init == "n" ]]; then
    git init
fi

git status
git add .

read -p "Ingrese el mensaje para el commit: " mensaje_commit
git commit -m "$mensaje_commit" || { echo "Error al crear el commit"; exit 1; }

# Manejar las configuraciones

read -p "¿Le aparece git config --global user.email y user.name? (s/n): " estado_config

if [[ $estado_config == "s" ]]; then
    read -p "Ingrese su correo electronico y su nombre: " correo nombre
    git config --global user.email "$correo"
    git config --global user.name "$nombre"
fi

read -p "¿Quieres agregar un repositorio remoto? (s/n): " repositorio_remoto

if [[ $repositorio_remoto == "s" ]]; then
    read -p "Ingrese la url del repositorio: " url_repositorio
    git remote add origin "$url_repositorio"
    git push -u origin master
fi

read -p "¿Quieres subir los cambios al repositorio remoto? (s/n): " subir_cambios

if [[ $subir_cambios == "s" ]]; then
    git push || { echo "Error al hacer push"; exit 1; }
fi


Ya lo hice y aun así dice el mismo  error:  /usr/bin/git.sh: no se puede ejecutar: no se ha encontrado el fichero requerido

Ya lo resolvi lo que hice fue borrar y crear el archivo de nuevo  y  funciono. Entonces, debería borrar esta pregunta o responder que como sugerencia que borre y se vuelva a crear el archivo de nuevo?

Por las dudas, un script es un simple archivo de texto a menos que lo marques como ejecutable chmod +x  tu_archivo.sh

Probablemente has abierto el script en Windows, haciendo que el script tenga \r\n en el fin de la linea en vez del estándar \n de UNIX. Como consecuencia, el sistema no encuentra el interpretador que le des en el shebang, ya que en vez de /bin/bash, ve /bin/bash\r y no existe el fichero /bin/bash\r. Se puede reproducir facilmente:
$ printf '#!/bin/bash\r\necho "hola!"\n' > ~/bin/foo.sh
$ chmod 744 ~/bin/foo.sh
$ ~/bin/foo.sh
bash: /home/terdon/bin/foo.sh: no se puede ejecutar: no se ha encontrado el fichero requerido

Basta entonces quitar los \r, con dos2unix ~/bin/git.sh o sed -i 's/\r//' ~/bin/git.sh y ya esta.
